# A hack or Greasemonkey script to move up the Advanced Search button on Google's search page?

Tags: search

Google has placed that button too low for my taste.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned Greasemonkey so assuming you're using Firefox, I recommend using [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108) in this case *("Stylish is to CSS what Greasemonkey is to JavaScript")*, and targeting the Advanced Search link through CSS. For example:

```
a[href~="/advanced_search"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

That will take all `anchors` on the page with a `href` attribute containing `/advanced_search` and position them 20px from the top left of your browser. See [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp) for more CSS positioning information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That led me to <i>input[type="submit"]</i> and then added the coordinates.

Comment: My mistake! Could only find Advanced Search links, no buttons. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors for more information on how to target page elements through their attributes. Hope that helps mate!

Comment: Actually, when I was posting the above comment, I saw the “Post Your Answer” button, at the bottom of this page, jump to the new place for the Google’s “Advanced Search” button, and I knew that there had to be an even better method to target that button. Eventually I found it: input[value="Advanced Search"]. Thanks again.

Comment: Correction: It was the "Answer Your Question" button that moved, and also the "Add Comment" button that appears on the right when this comment box opens.

Comment: In regards to your CSS rule affecting sites other than Google:

@-moz-document domain("www.google.com") {
    input[value="Advanced Search"] { .. }
}

I should've mentioned this to begin with, but I had some memory this was included in the default Stylish userstyle - sorry.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@-moz-document

Comment: The default was: @-moz-document url("http://www.google.com/advanced_search?hl=en"). Why that happened, I have no idea, but I'm guessing I'm not going to be running into many objects with the 'Advanced Search' value.
BTW, any ideas on how to change the default value in the ‘Results per page:’ box?

Comment: That's Greasemonkey's domain and not too difficult, though for the sake of keeping this question relevant, create a new question ("Greasemonkey - change default dropdown selection" or similar) - I'll keep an eye out.