# A Greasemonkey script that will select an item from a dropdown menu on Google’s Advanced Search page?

Tags: google-search, greasemonkey

‘Results per page:,’ for example.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit. I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, Please elaborate in detail.

Answer (score 2):

**Alternate solution to using Greasemonkey/Javascript**

From your [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/40166/a-hack-or-greasemonkey-script-to-move-up-the-advanced-search-button-on-googles-s/40191#40191), I get the impression you do alot of advanced searching. Depending on how similar each of your searches are, it may be easier to use GET arguments used by Google in their URLs and create a Firefox quick search.

**Google URL**

```
http://google.com.au/search?hl=en&as_q=Super+User&num=50&as_filetype=pdf&as_sitesearch=superuser.com

as_q = your keywords  
num = results per page  
as_filetype = filetype  
as_sitesearch = a site to search
etc..
```

**Example**

A quick search which searches superuser.com and displays 25 results per page would be:

```
http://google.com.au/search?hl=en&as_q=%s&num=25&as_sitesearch=superuser.com
```

**To create a quick search:**

1. 'Organise Bookmarks'(Ctrl + Shift + B)
2. Right click > 'New Bookmark'
3. Name your quick search bookmark
4. Enter the URL of your search string (example above) as the 'location' - include `%s` where your search string is to be placed in the URL
5. Enter a keyword to trigger the search